# Splitting list of possibly nested function expressions in Python

Tags: python, list, split

PostgreSQL allows indexes to be created on expressions, e.g., `CREATE INDEX ON films ((lower(title)))`. It also has a `pg_get_expr()` information function that translates the internal format of the expression into text, i.e., `lower(title)` in the former example.  The expressions can get quite hairy at times.  Here are some examples (in Python):

```
sample_exprs = [
    'lower(c2)',
    'lower(c2), lower(c3)',
    "btrim(c3, 'x'::text), lower(c2)",
    "date_part('month'::text, dt), date_part('day'::text, dt)",
    '"substring"(c2, "position"(c2, \'_begin\'::text)), "substring"(c2, "position"(c2, \'_end\'::text))',
    "(((c2)::text || ', '::text) || c3), ((c3 || ' '::text) || (c2)::text)",
    'f1(f2(arga, f3()), arg1), f4(arg2, f5(argb, argc)), f6(arg3)']
```

The last item isn't really from Postgres but is just an extreme example of what my code ought to handle.

I wrote a Python function to split the textual lists into the component expressions. For example, that last item is broken down into:

```
 f1(f2(arga, f3()), arg1)
 f4(arg2, f5(argb, argc))
 f6(arg3)
```

I experimented with `str` methods like `find()` and `count()` and also considered regexes, but in the end I wrote a function that is what I would have written in C (essentially counting open and close parens to find where to break the text).  Here's the function:

```
def split_exprs(idx_exprs):
    keyexprs = []
    nopen = nclose = beg = curr = 0
    for c in idx_exprs:
        curr += 1
        if c == '(':
            nopen += 1
        elif c == ')':
            nclose += 1
            if nopen > 0 and nopen == nclose:
                if idx_exprs[beg] == ',':
                    beg += 1
                if idx_exprs[beg] == ' ':
                    beg += 1
                keyexprs.append(idx_exprs[beg:curr])
                beg = curr
                nopen = nclose = 0
    return keyexprs
```

The question is whether there is a more Pythonic or elegant way to do this or to use regexes to solve this.

Comment: Have a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for some inspiration

Comment: Regexes may not have anything elegant. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text%3f

Comment: Yes, I've become convinced that regexes can't be used because state-machines can't count the nesting of parentheses without the help of a stack, i.e.,a PDA is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make it more pythonic, the only way I can think is readability.

Additionally I avoid one branch and one variable by counting stacks. The only pythonic suggestion I can give is to use the 'index' variable with the `enumerate(...)` function. As in

`for i, j in enumerate(<iterable>)`

This will create a variable, `i`, that will equal the current loop number, where `j` will be the expected iteration variable.

```
def split_fns(fns):
    paren_stack_level = 0
    last_pos = 0
    output = []
    for curr_pos, curr_char in enumerate(fns):
        if curr_char == "(":
            paren_stack_level += 1
        elif curr_char == ")":
            paren_stack_level -= 1
            if not paren_stack_level:
                output.append( fns[last_pos:curr_pos+1].lstrip(" ,") )
                last_pos = curr_pos+1
    return output

for i in sample_exprs:
    print(split_fns(i))
```

Comment: The single stack_level variable is certainly an improvement. However, the range(len(fns)) doesn't strike me as pythonic, and I don't know if accessing each character as fns[curr_pos] is more efficient (my instinct says no, but I haven't benchmarked it).

Comment: @JoeAbbate `range(len(<item>))` isn't incredibly uncommon in python, in my experience. And you're right, `fns[curr_pos]` isn't efficient. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version, more pythonic, less clutter I think, and works on stream of chars , though I don't see any advantage in that :)

```
def split_fns(fns):
    level = 0
    stack = [[]]
    for ch in fns:
        if level == 0 and ch in [' ',',']:
            continue        
        stack[-1].append(ch)

        if ch == "(":
            level += 1
        elif ch == ")":
            level -= 1
            if level == 0:
                stack.append([])

    return ["".join(t) for t in stack if t]
```

Comment: I'm impressed with the lateral thinking, though one thing to consider:

For characters outside the stack, 2-5 comparisons are made, 2-3 if they're symbols. 2-4 for parentheses, and 4 to determine a function is complete.

For, as an example, mine, the numbers are 2, 2, 1-2, and 5-7 (potentially 4 if rewritten intelligently)

Comment: @jsvk I assume more than speed clarity is the criteria here, otherwise I would write it in C

Comment: there are more reasons to write efficient code than speed, but I see where you're coming from; clarity is a vital part of being pythonic.